# The name 'FormView1' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net, code-behind, formview

I have a formview on an aspx page

CODE BEHIND

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
Label imgBG_userText = FormView1.FindControl("imgBG_user") as Label;
...
```

ASPX PAGE

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="IDeditorLanguage" DataSourceID="SQL_cookStatus">
     <ItemTemplate>
     ....
     </ItemTemplate>
```

I get an error "The name 'FormView1' does not exist in the current context". I'm going crazy trying to figure out what goes wrong. I didn't have a problem with the code until I made a copy of the aspx page in the project and then deleted the file copy, then the error started.... I didn't change the code. Has anyone had the same problem before?`

Thanks

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this piece of code. Are you sure you pasted exactly the code where the error is related to?

Comment: Since you are saying that the error started after you made a copy of the file.. make sure that the `.aspx` refernces the actual codebehind file

Comment: Well the problem was solved after I re-started the application. But don't ask me how! Sometimes technology works in mysterious ways....

Comment: Nothing works in mysterious way every thing has a reason :).

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ So what was the reason of my problem...? LOL!